# Web Server not loading index pages

Tags: iis, web-hosting

Hi we have a website which was working fine and hosted on microsoft IIS 6.0 shared hosting. However today theres some strange behaviour. The website is not loading the index pages by default. So for instance if i visit the website www.websitename.com it will show a blank page. However if I go to www.websitename.com/index.html it will load the page fine. Same is happening with the folders so for eg going to www.websitename.com/foldername will show a blank page but going to www.websitename.comn/foldername/index.php will open fine

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue with default documents, this may help http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320051

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever changed something either on the index page file or IIS　setting. It's hard to diagnose the problem based on your information given.